# Was the term 'final' a misnomer for the Gryffindor-Slytherin match in Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, quidditch

The Gryffindor-Slytherin match was referred to as the **final** in *Prisoner of Azkaban*. But was that the correct term to use? Wasn't it just one of six league matches?

#### Note

This isn't a duplicate of [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/148987/85755) question. That *assumes that the House Trophy consists of six league matches, while my question asks whether there is any canon evidence for the format, depending on which one could say if the word 'final' is applicable in the case mentioned above.*

### My thoughts

I think this can be answered if we can say definitively whether the House Trophy consisted of **six**(in the round robin system) or **seven**(six league matches plus a final) matches.

I find that evidence kind of points to the first possibility, as:

- The match in question was actually rescheduled, and was supposed to be the first match of the season.
- The House Trophy typically ends with a Gryffindor-Ravenclaw match, unlikely if the system had a final. Unlikely because Gryffindor's performances are usually not strong enough to make to the 'final' (if there was one), and the team's fate usually hangs in the balance before the last match. Plus, if there was a final, Gryffindor and Ravenclaw should have met before in the group stage, but no allusion is made to such a match.
- Wood keeps telling Harry to catch the Snitch only if they are more than fifty points up.<sup>1</sup> That would be unnecessary if the match was a final as a final is a 'winner-takes-all' kind of match.

### My question

Is there any **definitive canon evidence** for whether the Hogwarts House Trophy  had a format consisting of *six league matches **plus a final***? Or did it  consist of just six league matches?

That would help understand if it was right to call the Gryffindor-Slytherin match in Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban a final.

---

> <sup>1</sup> 'So you must *only* catch it if we're *more* than fifty points up,' Wood told Harry constantly.
> <sub>The Quidditch Final, Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban</sub>

Comment: You're over-thinking it.  In this context, "final match" just means "the last match of the year".

Comment: @HarryJohnston I used to think so too, but this made me rethink.https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/168127/do-games-of-quidditch-at-hogwarts-have-any-sort-of-time-limits/168189#comment449404_168189

Comment: I think this falls into the category "ms Rowling as no idea how sports work and neither does she care". Basically anything concerning sports and numbers doesn't make sense in the hp books, the lack of expertise meet btw in the fact that they have a couple of pro teams in such a small community.

Comment: @Raditz_35 Succinct, but I was hoping for an in-universe answer! :D

Comment: In that case, people often call games a final if they have the same character even though played in a league modus

Comment: @Raditz_35 That sounds plausible, I was wondering if the number of matches was explicitly stated anywhere.

Comment: @Raditz_35 BTW you mean that the match was called a final since Gryffindor and Slytherin were the only teams still left in the running for the trophy before the match?

Comment: This is how I always understood it, in combination with thr she doesnt know sports thing. You find that quite often in soccer for example. Btw this might be a case of bad editting. Final sounds more exciting

Comment: @Raditz_35 While what you say seems rather likeky, I'll be satisfied if an answer provides conclusive evidence either way. As far as I remember, the number of matches wasn't mentioned explicitly anywhere in the books (I don't know whether the same applies to Pottermore).

Comment: @HarryWeasley, I think the answer you link to is just wrong on that point.  Six games are played each year.  To the best of my knowledge, there's absolutely no indication of a seventh.  If the last game of the year was an extra game, then Slytherin and Gryffindor would have had to have played already, and they hadn't.

Comment: @HarryJohnston That's what I thought, too -- I used similar reasoning in my question. I am looking for some kind of canon *confirmation*, though, that there were indeed only six games every year.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reasoning for 6 games in the previous question is sound, and the assumption underlying Cup victory in this question is misplaced because The Quidditch Cup is awarded based on **accumulated points**, not a pure bracket system. *The final game of the season can determine the ultimate victor because of points, not game victory. There is much evidence for this in the books:*

> "..interest in the Gryffindor-Ravenclaw game was running extremely
>   high throughout the school, for **the match would decide the
>   Championship, which was still wide open**.
>
> **If Gryffindor beat Ravenclaw by a margin of three-hundred points** (a tall order, and yet Harry had never known his team to fly better)
>   then **they would win the Championship**.
>
> **If the won by less than than three-hundred points, they would come second to Ravenclaw**
>
> **If they lost by a hundred point they would be third behind Hufflepuff,**
>
> **and if they lost by more than a hundred, they would be in fourth place**....

*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Ch. 24 - Sectumsempra*

[formatted for easier illustration of the answer, but word for word quote of the US digital text]

Thus, we can see that Quidditch at Hogwarts is similar in some ways to [Premier League (UK football)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premier_League#Competition) standings as well as the House Cup (Hogwarts) in that an overall winner is determined based on points, not a bracket.

As an example from Premiere Leauge (wiki) - "Teams receive three points for a win and one point for a draw. No points are awarded for a loss. Teams are ranked by total points, then goal difference".

This has been seen at Hogwarts as well where, "final standings in the competition are based on the total amount of points won over all matches played, rather than the number of victories.[2](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Inter-House_Quidditch_Cup#cite_note-POA15-0) It is entirely possible for one team to lose to another, but still claim the Cup if their points from previous games were high enough". - [source](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Inter-House_Quidditch_Cup#cite_note-POA15-0)

> "Slytherin was leading the tournament by exactly two hundred points.
>   This meant (as Wood constantly reminded his team) that ***they needed
>   to win the match by more than that amount to win the Cup***....'So,
>   you must catch it [the Snitch] only if we're more than fifty points
>   up', Wood told Harry constantly. 'Only if we're more than fifty points
>   up, Harry, or we win the match but lose the Cup'"

*-Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Ch. 15 - The Quidditch Final*

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It sounds the most reasonable explanation for what I've read in the books. And yes,  the similarity with soccer leagues was unmistakeable. Thanks for your answer, I've accepted and upvoted it!

Comment: I guess goal difference counts for points.

Comment: Excellent.  I'd like to add that (as far as I'm aware) the *only* thing in-universe to even suggest otherwise is Hermione referring to one game as "the Quidditch Final".  This is the woman who brought us "wonky faints", mind you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In this case it just meant last match of the season which is fine since there isn't any tournament bracket (which would have an actual final) in Hogwarts Quidditch.

Comment: This is a decent answer, if you could provide a quote from the book to support your conclusion, that would be better. I recommend the quote that OP derived their question from.